# How can we validated whether there are no cycles in the DAG objects

Tags: pytest, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I am writing a unit test for my ETLs and as a process, I want to test all Dags to make sure that they do not have cycles. After reading Data Pipelines with Apache Airflow by Bas Harenslak and Julian de Ruiter I see they are using DAG.test_cycle(), the DAG here is imported from the module airflow.models.dag but when I run the code I get an error that AttributeError: 'DAG' object has no attribute 'test_cycle'

Here is my code snippet

```
import glob
import importlib
import os

import pytest
from airflow.models.dag import DAG

DAG_PATH = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(file), “…”, “…”, “dags/**/*.py”)
DAG_FILES = glob.glob(DAG_PATH, recursive=True)

@pytest.mark.parametrize("dag_file", DAG_FILES)
def test_dag_integrity(dag_file):
    module_name, _ = os.path.splitext(dag_file)
    module_path = os.path.join(DAG_PATH, dag_file)
    mod_spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location(module_name, module_path)
    module = importlib.util.module_from_spec(mod_spec)
    mod_spec.loader.exec_module(module)

    dag_objects = [var for var in vars(module).values() if isinstance(var, DAG)]

    assert dag_objects

    for dag in dag_objects:
        dag.test_cycle()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update on the above answers:

Due to the conflicts caused by having a function with "test" in the name, Airflow team renamed the function to check_cycle

`from airflow.utils.dag_cycle_tester import check_cycle`

To run the actual test, change the final two line to read `check_cycle(dag)`

Answer (score 7):

In Airflow `2.0.0` or greater, you could use `test_cycle()` function that takes a `dag` as argument:

```py
def test_cycle(dag):
    """
    Check to see if there are any cycles in the DAG. Returns False if no cycle found,
    otherwise raises exception.
    """
```

[Source](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/65519ab83ddf4bd6fc30c435b5bfccefcb14d596/airflow/utils/dag_cycle_tester.py#L27)

Import like this:

`from airflow.utils.dag_cycle_tester import test_cycle`

You could find an example in the definition of [DagBag](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/_modules/airflow/models/dagbag.html) class.

Comment: For some reason i get the below error when running this. Any ideas on how to resolve?

def test_cycle(dag):
E       fixture 'dag' not found
>       available fixtures: anyio_backend, anyio_backend_name, anyio_backend_options, cache, capfd, capfdbinary, caplog, capsys, capsysbinary, celery_app, celery_class_tasks, c

Comment: @adan11 Your issue is that when you put an argument in any function with a name starting with "test" in a pytest suite, pytest thinks it's a test, and assumes the arguments being passed are fixtures.

If you have a newer version of Airflow, this function has been renamed to "check_cycle".  If you don't, simply alias the function on import as Makr did in their answer on this page.

Answer (score 5):

In case someone faced the same issue as @adan11 have mentioned when using the test_cycle method, the problem with that is when we compile our test suite, our test tool ie. pytest, will parse the test_cycle method upon importing it.

e.g

```
# Pytest will collect this function
from airflow.utils.dag_cycle_tester import test_cycle
```

Pytest will ignore it when we use an alias name like below:

```
from airflow.utils.dag_cycle_tester import test_cycle as _test_cycle
```

This will work depending on your test configuration.